# Calculate the Area of the space defined by two lines $\varepsilon_{1},\varepsilon_{2}$ and a curve $c_{1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm starting a class on Advanced Mathematics I next semester and I found a sheet of the class'es 2012 final exams, so I'm slowly trying to solve the exercises in it or find the general layout. I will be posting a lot of questions with the exercises I find challenging, and I would like to ask for any help or methodologies that will make it easier for me to solve.

I understand the whole ordeal is categorized as **"homework"**, but any assistance would be appreciated, as I'm completely clueless and I would like to be prepared.

The following exercise is $Ex. 12$, graded for $12\%$.

> Calculate the Area of the space defined by two lines, $\varepsilon_{1}:y=4x-3,\;\;\varepsilon_{2}: -4x-3\;$ and the curve $c_{1}: y = 1 + x^{2}\;$.

The extend of my knowledge is the *hunch* that I will have to use integrals for this, but unfortunately that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve such problems, always plot the given curves. This will help you figure out what integrals you need to evaluate.

[image: Plot of given lines]

For any $x=x_0$ the area will be defined by two enclosing curves; one above and one below. First note that the are defined by the three curves begins wherever $x^2+1=-4x-3$. Let's call that point $x_a$. For $x_a \le x \le 0$ The first part of the area defined by the three curves is

$$
A_1=\int_{x_a}^{0}(x^2+1)-(-4x-3)dx
$$

Because the difference of the two functions gives the height of the area and integrating over $x \in (x_a,0)$ gives the length so to speak.

Accordingly, the rest of the area is given by

$$
A_2=\int_{0}^{x_b}(x^2+1)-(4x-3)dx
$$

Where $x_b$ is the intersection of $x^2+1$ and $4x-3$, of course. The total area is $A=A_1+A_2$

Note that sometimes there are simpler ways to calculate the area, such as finding the area of the triangle and subtracting the area of the parabola inside the triangle, which has already been suggested in another answer. This method, however, is the more general one in case no such "shortcut" exists.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, the general case. Thank you very much! Would you mind elaborating or linking to a methodology on how I would go about solving the actual integrals themselves, or finding a closed type?

Comment: @DimitrisS. I'm not aware of any good online resources on integration so I'll leave that up to someone else to answer or you can search for yourself. It would me most practical for you to attend a class or find a book on the subject than me explaining it step by step as there is quite a bit of theory to it. Know for now that $x^a$ is a known function with $\int x^a = \frac{1}{a+1} x^{a+1}$ and the linearity of the integrate operator means that you can use the previous formula for each factor of a polynomial to get the result.

Comment: I remember the general rule from High School, thank you. I'll brush up on it. I also remember the simple rule on getting a numerical result from integrals with definite limits, so that's bound to come in useful in producing an answer. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Here is a diagram of the situation. Calculate the area of the triangle, and then subtract the area formed by the parabola.

The area will be $\displaystyle A=16-\int_{-2}^25-(1+x^2)\,dx$.

I think you can take it from here. If not, let me know.

[image]

---

**Edit**

[image]

First, we take the area of the whole triangle, which is $4\cdot8\cdot\frac12=16$

[image]

Then, we substract the area formed by $y=5$ and the parabola $y=x^2+1$. This area is $\int_{-2}^25-(1+x^2)\,dx$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the diagram. Isn't this a bottom-to-top approach, though? Would this stand as an examination solution, drawing the plot then announcing that you're subtracting the area of the parabola from the area of the triangle?

Also, would you mind explaining how you ended up with that integral?

Comment: Yes, I think it will stand. I will edit the post a bit and explain how I ended up with the integral.

Comment: As long as you explain your reasoning, this solution should be considered 100% valid. Writing down formulas and expecting the examiner to figure out why it's true is always a bad idea.